# How is it possible that this ratio revert to the mean?

Tags: r, mean

I'm testing the ratio on the chart below with ADF.

[Ratio chart](http://imageshack.us/f/402/ratior.png/)

The function I'm using is:

```
adfTest(ratio, type='nc')
```

on fUnitRoots library.

The result (p-value) is: **0.01301** It is **very low** so the serie should be mean-reverting.

(@Statistical Please do not hate me for this brutal explanation)

Seeing the chart the ratio doesn't seem very "mean-reverting", I'm talking about a visual check of the ratio. What do you think about that?

Thank you!

Comment: just a quick comment, it seems that the process is mean-reverting (for a long period it went around zero, strange for the ratio though, and... hm negative values looks also strange, what the definition of ratio is?) but experienced a structural break at the end of a period. Try Zivot-Andrew (`ur.za`) test from `urca` library.

Comment: Hi Dmitrij, the ratio is: x - beta*y I have done a linear regression, then multiplied the variable by their coefficients and develop the ratio as I told. Btw this serie seems doesn't pass the KPSS test...it returns 0.01, Maybe do I only have to check the serie with KPSS or Zivot-Andrew ?

Comment: @ Dmitrij I tried ZA test, its result is: Teststatistic: -9.1024  
Critical values: 0.01= -4.93 0.05= -4.42 0.1= -4.11

Comment: that means I was correct in my guess, it is a structural break in the data not the unit-root problem. Probably in the summary for the test there is an estimated change point of the structural break. Regarding the definition of a ratio, it seems that this is just the residual from the linear regression, well for log-log it could be called so.